# Theta. Get faucet testnet tokens

Tags: blockchain

I research the THETA blockchain and can't find the way to get testnet tokens. There are some resources in net, but all of them seem doudbtful. How to get testnet Theta and where?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that it has been more than a year since it has been possible to start deploying smart contracts in solidity on this network, they have not enabled any faucet to acquire tokens for testing.
It is a bad sign or at least a bad image for new developers.